# Integrating Propel ORM into Kohana 3.x?

Tags: kohana-3, propel, kohana-orm

I'm using Kohana 3.x for about a month now, I am pretty happy so far.
But recently a friend of mine recommended the Propel-ORM to me. Has anybody experience with both the Kohana ORM and Propel ORM? I would like to now what are the advantages and disadvanteges when using Propel over the built-in Kohana-ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've some experience with Propel ORM. I can tell you about some of its pros/cons.

Until version 1.3, querying was quite counter-intuitive in a lot of cases, but latest versions (1.5) offer an ActiveRecord implementation and a nice querying syntax like Doctrine.

Propel developers take a lot of care on performance, see : http://propel.posterous.com/how-fast-is-propel-15 and Propel has lot of interesting features to handle complex DB schemas (i18n, nested sets, concrete inheritance...)

However, Propel requires some "old" technologies (IMO) like Phing (requires PEAR).

HTH.